# Bitcode errors on Release build configuration but not Archive

Tags: ios, xcode, bitcode

I have quite a complicated project structure consisting of many frameworks and dependencies.

I have a framework target which contains all the classes I include in my WatchKit extensions. This requires the framework be built with Bitcode support (which it is).

I have no trouble archiving my app from Xcode's Product menu, but when I try to build manually using the Release configuration, I run into this linker error.

> ld: bitcode bundle could not be generated because '/Users/ricky/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Coventry-ammghqykwgwisogpgstgfdmkzqjh/Build/Products/Release-watchos/Silverlake-Watch.framework/Silverlake-Watch' was built without full bitcode. All frameworks and dylibs for bitcode must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build for architecture armv7k
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

There are then several other errors that stem from this framework not properly linking. Does anyone have any idea what would be causing different build behaviour between the Xcode Archive process and my manual Release build?